# My Models giving negative scores

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression

I am new to Data Science. I am trying to use [following](https://www.kaggle.com/maha48/villas-price-dataset) dataset in order to predict prices for some reason my models except for decision tree is giving negative score.
Please help me to build this model. I've tried multiple ways but still not able to succeed. Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")

X = data.iloc[:,2:].values
Y = data.iloc[:,0].values

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(sparse = False),[0,1])],remainder = 'passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
X = np.delete(X,[0,16],1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR
svr = SVR()
random = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=40)
reg = LinearRegression()
dec_tress = DecisionTreeClassifier()

def get_score(model,x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test):
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
return model.score(x_test,y_test)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()



   from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits = 3)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,Y):

  x_train,x_test, y_train,y_test = X[train_index],X[test_index],Y[train_index],Y[test_index]

  x_train[:,:] = sc.fit_transform(x_train[:,:])
  x_test[:,:] = sc.transform(x_test[:,:])

  linear.append(get_score(reg,x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test))
  decision_tree.append(get_score(dec_tress,x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test))
  random_forest.append(get_score(reg,x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test))
  svm_score.append(get_score(svr,x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test))



print(linear)
print(decision_tree)
print(svm_score)
```

Printed Scores :

```
[-5.001783664305169e+21, -2.433328033798912e+25, -3.9981849795247057e+23]
[0.12684989429175475, 0.1673728813559322, 0.1016949152542373]
[-0.009105278318407573, -0.08897103667576811, -0.028828939964688157]
```

I have tried K-fold with 10 splits as well.

Please if anyone could help to solve this. I have tried almost all the models not getting good accuracy.

You can see the graphs [image: below].

[image]

[image]

There is no linear relation between the independent and dependent variable.Hence I tried logistic regression the max score I get is 0.22.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. You're working with scaled values everywhere so the predictions are also scaled, this is certainly why you get negative values. You need to reverse the scaling in order to obtain the real values.

Comment: Than you Erwan for your reply could you please explain a little more. How can I reverse the scaling did you mean I need to use inverse scaling to the predictions ? or x_test

Comment: Erwan the above printed values are not predictions these are the scores.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize. Well then it's simple: by default the `score` function calculates the R^2 score. I'm not familiar with it but according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor.html#sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor.score) this value can be negative: "The best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse)".

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to calculate this score though, especially for every fold.

Comment: How can i enhance the model. I am trying to use logistic regression now

Comment: I don't know how to interpret these R2 scores, do you? Do you have any baseline model to compare performance? Otherwise you're just aiming in the dark.

Comment: What do you mean by baseline model. What I have heard and red is you should try all the models until you get the perfect one.

Comment: I think that there are a few issues with your strategy: first, if we cannot understand the evaluation score then there's no way to say for sure if the performance is good or bad, so there's no reason to consider that your current results are bad. For example it's possible that the dataset is "hard" and you're already obtaining the best possible performance. This is also why I'm talking about a baseline model, i.e. a simple model which can be used a reference. The linear regression one could be considered a baseline model, because linear regression is very simple. It's not surprising that ...

Comment: ... its performance is not as good as the others. Another way to have some reference would be if you know of somebody else who developed a model with this data.

Comment: I don't know anyone who have used this data to develop but I know one thing now LinearRegression can't be used here since only one feature is a linear that too very minor the best model for this is logisticRegression however the data set is real world data set taken from Aqar and I got it from kaggel.

Comment: Do you think the steps I performed and the way I performed them is good practice and there is no error in my steps.

Comment: I have added the images for the relationship graphs kindly check it

Comment: The steps look ok to me, I don't see any error. But I would recommend using an evaluation measure that you can understand and explain. Mean Absolute Error is a very simple one for example, that might be more informative. Yes the graphs show that there is no linear relation between features price, but that's not very surprising.